# ctypes ReadProcessMemory Python, stops reading if the value ends with 00

Tags: python, ctypes, readprocessmemory

I am having trouble with reading some memory addresses. Most work fine, except when they end in "00", like this one: "1C1F3400" .

I have this code for the reading function itself:¨

```
def readValue(self, address, bytes, outputType):
    theValue = ctypes.create_string_buffer(bytes)
    intAddress = int(address,16)
    if(outputType == 'float'):
        pass
    if(outputType == 'string'):
        bytes = 50
        theValue = ctypes.create_string_buffer(bytes)
    if self.rPM(self.PROCESS.handle,intAddress,theValue,bytes,None):
        pass
    else:
        print 'Failed to read address ' + address

    if(outputType == 'address'):
        #print theValue.value
        try:
            return hex(struct.unpack('<L',theValue.value)[0])
        except struct.error:
            print str(theValue.value) + ' not valid'
            self.memReadLog.write('Unreadable address at: ' + str(address) + '\n')
            self.memReadLog.write('The value read was: ' + str(theValue.value) + '\n')


            return 'error'
```

Then I have this code for the part where it sometimes fails, this takes an array of preset pointers and finds the correct address after going through them all. The module address is found earlier and is in a class variable.

```
def addressByPointer(self,initialAddress, bytes, offsetArray):

    #print initialAddress
    #print self.modAddress
    currentAddress = self.addHex(initialAddress,self.modAddress)
    #print currentAddress
    OALength = len(offsetArray)
    counter = 0
    for offset in offsetArray:
        print 'Before adding: CA: ' + currentAddress + ' Offset: ' + offset 
        currentAddress = self.addHex(currentAddress,offset) 
        print 'Read ' + currentAddress
        if(counter == OALength-1):
            return currentAddress
        currentAddress = self.readValue(currentAddress,bytes,'address')
        if(currentAddress == 'error'):
            break
        print ' .. and found ' + str(currentAddress)
        counter += 1
```

This is how it works when there is no 00 at the end of the value read from the last address:

```
Before adding: CA: 1662aa4 Offset: 0x0
Read 1662aa4
 .. and found 0x4743d30
Before adding: CA: 0x4743d30 Offset: 0x0
Read 4743d30
.. and found 0x19416408
```

And this value holds the expected result(an integer in this case).

But sometimes I get this:

```
Read 1c1f46a8
 .. and found 0x19416408
Before adding: CA: 0x19416408 Offset: 0x6B0
Read 19416ab8
 not valid
```

From reading the value manually with Cheat Engine it is supposed to equal 1C1F3400. And following the pointer chain from there works as it should and the end result is the correct value. The ReadProcessMemory function does not return an error(it returns 1), but the unpack fails because the value read by rPM is 0.

Since the failing address always has 00 on the end I am guessing that stops the read early? Is there any way to get around this or any obvious mistake I am making? Or maybe my assumption is wrong.

I may have other mistakes too, unpacking bytes is confusing to me. I have read many other questions but most of them are about the memory read failing due to a wrong handle or another error returned by the rPM function, in this case it says it succeeds but the output is 0(not the return value). It doesn't look like the unpack function is the issue because by printing "theValue" I can see that becomes 0 (and therefore the unpack fails). It also works correctly except for these values.

I've tested to make sure and it also failed upon finding the values 0x1B334D00,0x04DA8300 as well as other values ending in 00. Can I do something like read 3 bytes and add on a 00 at the end or does it not work that way? Other than that, my type for "theValue" might be wrong, or the struct.unpack arguments might be faulty.

I did search a lot but I may have missed some obvious answers along the way, sorry if I did.

Edit: What I am doing is reading pointer values in order to get to the correct memory address. I have offsets and an initial address as well as the module address stored for each address I am looking to find. The one failing is different every time. So each read should give a pointer address back, then I add an offset to it and get the next address. But sometimes it fails along the way, specifically when the pointer has a hex address ending in 00. Then ReadProcessMemory returns nothing instead of the address(but not an error, just nothing). I know the address is there because it can be seen when using other tools, but the way it is used here returns nothing instead of the address, and I don't know why. The struct usage should be fine, I think the problem is with ReadProcessMemory.

The struct error says "unpack requires a string argument of length 4", I think that is because ReadProcessMemory returned nothing. I get the same error if I read an address holding a value of 0 and use struct.unpack on it, I thought that was normal.

Comment: It is absolutely not clear what you are trying to do in the first place. You seem to be getting getting a `struct.error` exception on `readValue()` but neither you nor we know why. However, `struct.error` exceptions have an argument that explains what is wrong. Get the argument with `except struct.error, errmsg:` (python 2.x) and print it.

Comment: Sorry about that. The struct.error is "unpack requires a string argument of length 4". And printing the value returned from ReadProcessMemory shows nothing. So that makes sense. But the value at that address is supposed to be for example "1B334D00" and be 4 bytes long. ReadProcessMemory does not return an error because no error occured though. I will try to rewrite a bit since it is unclear still.

Comment: The value attribute of a `c_char` array is a null-terminated string. But your real mistake is assuming you have to pass a `c_char` array here. Just pass a `c_void_p` instance by reference, e.g. assign `theValue = ctypes.c_void_p()` and pass `ctypes.byref(theValue)` as the `lpBuffer` parameter and `ctypes.sizeof(theValue)` as the `nSize` parameter. The result is `theValue.value`. There's no need for `struct.unpack`.

Comment: Also, don't assume a pointer is 4 bytes or the size of `c_long`. And never pass or get a pointer using the default `c_int` type. That's likely to yield truncated garbage on a 64-bit system. For a pointer result, you must define `restype` as a pointer type. For pointer arguments you can either define `argtypes` or selectively wrap each pointer argument in a ctypes pointer type. Otherwise your code isn't portable to 64-bit systems.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works without problems now after changing the parameter types. I can't seem to find how to mark as answer.